# Coming Amazon FPS Changes

Tags: amazon-fps

Per the notice sent by Amazon:

"Amazon Payments has released important code updates to further strengthen the security and reliability of our products. These updates specifically address code written in ASP, Java and PHP"

Does the above mean there is no API change, but changes just to the examples provided?

I don't use any of these, can someone who does describe the nature of the changes?

jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question I know, but here's your answer:

The major change is to the option: CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST (from 1 to 2). You can find more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> 1 to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate.
>   2 to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it
>   matches the hostname provided. In production environments the value of
>   this option should be kept at 2 (default value).
>
> Support for value 1 removed in cURL 7.28.1